# Find the intersection between $\sin(2x)+2x$ and one of its tangent lines $2x-1$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

> The image represents:
>
> - part of the graph of $f$, $f(x) = \sin(2x)+2x$
> - point A, which belongs to the graph of f, with x-coordinate $\frac{\pi}{4}$
> - points E($\frac{1}{2}$,0) and F(0,-1)
> - part of EF, tangent to the graph f at point D
>
> Find the  exact value of the area of the trapezoid [ABCD].
>
> [image]

First I tried to find the equation of the tangent line:

$$r = mx-1$$

$$\\$$

$$0 = \frac{x}{2}-1 \Leftrightarrow 2 = x$$

And so $r = 2x-1$. Then I tried finding the x-coordinate of D by trying to find a point where the slope would be 2:

$$f'(x) = 2\cos (2x)+2$$

$$\\$$

$$2 = 2\cos(2x)+2 \Leftrightarrow \\
0 = \cos(2x) \Leftrightarrow \\
(...) \Leftrightarrow \\
x = \frac{\pi(4k+1)}{4} \lor x = \frac{\pi(4k-1)}{4}$$

Then I tried to find the first value for k for which x would be greater than $\pi/2$. Using the calculator I figured that was

$$\frac{\pi}{4}(4\cdot1-1) = \frac{3\pi}{4}$$

But then when I tried calculating the value (not the exact one) in my calc to make sure it was correct, I got:

$$\frac{f(\pi/4)+f(3\pi/4)}{2}\cdot (\frac{3\pi}{4}-\frac{\pi}{4}) \approx 8.952...$$

And my book states the solution is

$$\frac{\pi^2}{2} \approx 4.9348...$$

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have made a typo pushing the buttons on the calculator. Doing the calculation, I get

$$\begin{split}\frac{f\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right) + f\left(\frac{3\pi}{4}\right)}{2}
\left(\frac{3\pi}{4} - \frac{\pi}{4}\right) &= \frac{\pi}{4}\left(\sin \pi/2 + \sin 3\pi/2 + \pi/2 + 3\pi/2\right) \\
&= \frac{\pi}{4}\left(1 - 1 + 2 \pi\right) \\
&= \pi^2/2\end{split}$$

Comment: Great, thanks. This seems to be happening a lot lately though. Do you know if TI calculators can interpret input wrongly if they are really old (like around 20 years)?

Comment: I don't know about TI calculators, sorry! I do recommend using sage or mathematica though! It's a lot easier to check your work with a modern computer algebra system.

Comment: Indeed, but they only allow calcs at the exam I'm studying for... in fact, I've heard that they are planning to ban even calculators in future exams, go figure. But I'll try those.